# How to check system lock before start activity in android

Tags: android

Now I'm developing custom messaging app in android.
I wanna check screen lock before take a look a message which is locked.
How can I do that?
Simply require and compare screen lock and start activity if screen lock passed.
Help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isScreenLocked() {
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)
            cordovaActivity.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)
            cordovaActivity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    return keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked() ||
            keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() ||
            !powerManager.isInteractive();
}
```